# How to enable Data Length Extension (DLE) in Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)

Tags: embedded-linux, bluetooth-gatt

I am working on embedded linux platform and I want to increase data length in BLE communication but I can't find an api function to change data packet length. The module used is SparkLAN AP6256. Is there any configuration parameter to enable DLE (Data Length Extension).

Currently I am using gattool to connect to the device (configured as ble device) and the data length is set to 23 bytes by default. Also tried using btgatt-server and btgatt-client but didn't see any option to enable DLE.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The same question came up before and there also a comprehensive answer/comment:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74114807/how-is-data-length-extension-dle-enabled-for-ble
Do you use latest tools and driver?

Comment: @Risto: The link is dead...